# Why doesn't this JSON decode into my struct?

Tags: json, go

I am sending this kind of array after calling JSON.stringify on it

```
{
  "世": 1,
  "界": 1,
  "最": 1,
  "強": 1
}
```

but am having trouble using json.NewDecoder.Decode on it, is my struct wrong?

```
type text struct {
    Text map[string]int
}
```

I am also having trouble sending that data back to the front end, how do I convert my data back to []byte or is there another method available to send json back to front end?

```
func PostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    log.Println("post start")
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        log.Println("in post but early return")
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var t text
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("I tried")
        log.Println(r.Body)
    }
    log.Println(t.Text)
    //w.Write([]byte(t.Text))     //throws conversion error
}
```

(I am trying to send data back and forth between front and back end to get the basics down before moving on and expanding)

Also what's printed from the log is

```
post start
map[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode the JSON value directly to a `map[string]int`. The map corresponds to the one object in the JSON value.

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
var t map[string]int
err := decoder.Decode(&t)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("I tried")
    log.Println(r.Body)
}
log.Println(t)
```

[similar playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/D0Wn-v4bcl)

Comment: This helped thank you! As for sending it back to the front end, is json.Marshal the way to go or would you recommend something else that would be better?